# Object doesn't support property or method 'facebox' in cshtml file

Tags: javascript, razor, methods, facebox

I want to show another cshtml (ex.cshtml) file in a Facebox popup window in one cshtml (this cshtml file contains the model also) file, but it is showing error like:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'facebox'

and anchor tag is

```
<"a href="ex" rel="facebox">Something  /a "<br />
```

here `ex` is ex.cshtml file. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>; <link src="src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script src="src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({ loadingImage: '', closeImage: '' }) }) </script>
```

code for ex.xshtml

```
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; <head> <title>Sample file</title> </head> <body> <h2>Hi Welcome to Aspdotnet-Suresh.com</h2> <img src="src/" /> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Here my code is 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<link src="src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage: '',
            closeImage: ''
        })
    })
</script>

Comment: ere is code for ex.xshtml

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sample file</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hi Welcome to Aspdotnet-Suresh.com</h2>
    <img src="src/" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you please post your code in the question not in the comment

Comment: i am not able to add if possible please provide solution

Comment: I have edited your question please check